# Intent Activity not firing?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm doing a basic activity of moving from one page to another.  Everything was going perfect until I get two pages deep into the app. I used the same exact code for each page class, put the activities in the manifest and made sure all words were spelled correctly, etc., but the intent doesn't do anything when I try to go three pages deep.  There are no error messages in the log at all.  When I click on a button on the third page, it just turns blue but doesn't move to the next page like the previous pages.  Here's my code:

from page 1 to 3:

Page1:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton(); }

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainMenu.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

    }
   }
```

Page 2: has more buttons...

```
   public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button;
Button button2;
Button button3;
Button button4;
Button button5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
    addListenerOnButton();
     }

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, OneMain.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
        }       
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TwoMain.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
        }       
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ThreeMain.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
        }       
    });

    button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, FourMain.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
        }       
    });

    button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, FiveMain.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
        }       
    });

          }
         }
```

Page 3:

```
   public class OneMain extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.one_main);

     }

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;



    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alphabet.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
        }       
    });



           }


          }
```

I also made sure I put in all the imports.  Someone help. I'm stuck :(.

Here is the manifest xml:

```
       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.juwar74.alarabic"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >



<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:launchMode="singleTop"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainMenu" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".OneMain" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".TwoMain" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ThreeMain" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".FourMain" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".FiveMain" >
    </activity>

    <activity
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:name=".OneVoc" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the code for the Alphabet.class

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

  public class Alphabet extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alphabet);

     }
```

}

Comment: Instead of using context inside Intent, try using youractivityname.this or getApplicationContext()

Comment: You have so many common ids. Please change them first, at least for maintenance purpose.

Comment: Can you please post the code for "Alphabet.java" class.

Comment: post your `manifest` file